# how to execute a loop with regexm command stata

Tags: loops, stata

I have a large text dataset in Stata that lists information about different research studies (data are in broad form, one row per study). Originally, I had a dataset with one variable per study (`conditions_l`) that listed the disease condition studied (could be cardiovascular disease, lymphoma, etc). I went through and coded each into different categories, for example, variable `code_c` represented cancer.
Example code:

```
gen code_c=0

replace code_c=code_c+1 if regexm(conditions_l, "leukemia")
```

Now, I have a dataset that has multiple condition variables per research study (instead of just conditions_l, I have `conditions_l1`, `conditions_l2`, etc. through `conditions_l212`). I want to use a loop to execute this on all of the condition variables but haven't been successful so far. So, if any of the condition variables for a given research study contain "lymphoma" I want to replace `code_c` with `code_c+1`. How might I change the code to run across multiple variables?

Comment: Strictly `regexm()` is a function, not a command.

Answer (score 1):

There is much that I don't understand about your sample code; for example, it seems to me you could have done `replace code_c=1 if ...`. However, building on the code you have, the following should do what I understand you to want.

```
gen code_c=0
generate t=0
forvalues i = 1/212 {
    /* only add 1 even if it appears in more than one condition */
    replace t=1 if regexm(conditions_l`i', "leukemia")
    }
replace code_c=code_c+t
```

With my initial comment in mind, I think this could have been written

```
gen code_c=0
forvalues i = 1/212 {
    replace code_c=1 if regexm(conditions_l`i', "leukemia")
    }
```